# How to use Sed/xmlparser to update multi line with many uniode characters

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I am working with sed to add new data after a specific match of pattern.
In this case, I can use sed for a single line and receiving exceptions while using multiline expressions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config xmlns="http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/2.1.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jfrog.org/xsd/artifactory-v2_1_7.xsd">
    <backups>
        <backup>
            <key>backup-weekly</key>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <cronExp>0 0 2 ? * SAT</cronExp>
            <retentionPeriodHours>336</retentionPeriodHours>
            <createArchive>false</createArchive>
            <excludedRepositories/>
        </backup>
    <backups>
</config>
```

I just need to add somthing right after `<enabled>false</enabled>` but need to verify that the enabled key should be below `<key>backup-weekly</key>` and updated content looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config xmlns="http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/2.1.7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jfrog.org/xsd/artifactory-v2_1_7.xsd">
    <backups>
        <backup>
            <key>backup-weekly</key>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <dir>/opt/jfrog/data/backup</dir>
            <cronExp>0 0 2 ? * SAT</cronExp>
            <retentionPeriodHours>336</retentionPeriodHours>
            <createArchive>false</createArchive>
            <excludedRepositories/>
        </backup>
    <backups>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it is to use an XSLT. For example, save this as *yourfile.xsl*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://artifactory.jfrog.org/xsd/2.1.7">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[name()='backup'][./*[name()='key']='backup-weekly']/*[name()='enabled'][.='false']">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></xsl:copy>
        <dir>/opt/jfrog/data/backup</dir>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and use *xsltproc* in this command line:

```
xsltproc yourfile.xsl yourfile.xml
```

Comment: [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (instead of `xsltproc`) can also be utilized to perform the transformation using the following command: `xml tr yourfile.xsl yourfile.xml > newfile.xml`. Note: you'll need to make sure that your source `.xml` is well formed though. Currently the OP's given example is missing a closing `</backups>` tag.

Comment: @RobC: it's probably a typo: when he has shorten the file to post it here, he has probably copy/pasted the beginning and rewritten the end by hand.

Comment: ...Yes possibly, or perhaps not using an XML aware editing tool to indicate such error. I thought I'd mention it anyway as I noticed that your answer hadn't been accepted ;)